# I'm getting a null pointer exception when I subclass an OnClickListener()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to subclass one of my `OnClickListener()` 's and I'm getting a 'null pointer' exception, but I'm not sure why.. I'm going nuts over this.. any help would be greatly appreciated..

Here is the code in my Utilities Class located in com.Tools

```
public class Utilities 
{
public static View.OnClickListener CreateOnClickListener(final Context context,final Class<?> cls)
{
    final Activity act = new Activity();
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent window = new Intent(context, cls);
                act.startActivity(window);
                act.finish();
            }
    };

    return listener;
}
}
```

And when I call it from my main class I do this:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(Utilities.CreateOnClickListener(MainMenu.this, SettingsMenu.class));
```

When I debug, the exception occurs on this line:

```
act.startActivity(window);
```

Any ideas??? Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: `window` is null. well, indeed `null` -- not even defined.

Comment: @Nishant: looks pretty defined to me...

Comment: when you debug, do you detect a null window, or null act?

Comment: I have    window defined as an Intent and are initializing it as a new Intent(context, cls);  Is that what you are referring to?  If I use those same three lines in the main class (the ones in the onClick()) it works just fine

Comment: @all -- sorry. I must be sleepy. How could I miss that line! Ignore my prev comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an `Activity` that you create out of thin air like that. It needs to be attached to the system to be useful. Besides, you don't need it. Try this implementation instead:

```
public class Utilities 
{
public static View.OnClickListener CreateOnClickListener(final Context context,final Class<?> cls)
{
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent window = new Intent(context, cls);
                context.startActivity(window);
            }
    };

    return listener;
}
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry! I posted the same answer at almost same time . I apologize..!!

Comment: @Adil Soomro "Oh sorry! I posted the same answer at almost same time . I apologize..!!"  I hope you get over that real soon.  There is nothing wrong with multiple answers.  At the very least, it assures the OP that it is not just one 'crazy person' suggesting something that won't work.

Comment: Yep. That way it's evidence of mass insanity instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think when you call

```
act.startActivity(window);
```

it should be called from current context.
i.e

```
context.startActivity(window);
```